# Pythonic way to parse huge string into fields

Tags: python, parsing, data-manipulation

I have several hundred files that contain email messages as strings. The filenames look like this:

```
00005.34bcaad58ad5f598f5d6af8cfa0c0465 --
00250.c7603b27a45284d12b49adf767b2b6fa --
00249.b9183324a9726e8b6c8779045a921243 --
00248.9599b06d2d2c08b57ff1de06316d66c0 --
00247.42534d5df0700cb2adf240556c539947 --
00246.fdaacadac7143848978ea0af07eed070 --
```

The content of those files looks similar the snippet below

```
Return-Path: <bounce-lghtml-2534368@sprocket.lockergnome.com>
Received: from lockergnome.com (sprocket.lockergnome.com [130.94.96.247])
    by dogma.slashnull.org (8.11.6/8.11.6) with SMTP id g6IKksJ07017
    for <qqqqqqqqqq-lg@spamassassin.taint.org>; Thu, 18 Jul 2002 21:46:54 +0100
X-Mailer: ListManager Web Interface
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2002 09:55:22 -0500
Subject: [Lockergnome Windows Daily]  Sticker Courtesy
To: qqqqqqqqqq-lg@spamassassin.taint.org
From: Lockergnome Windows Daily <subscriptions@lockergnome.com>
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:leave-lghtml-2534368N@sprocket.lockergnome.com>
List-Subscribe: <mailto:subscribe-lghtml@sprocket.lockergnome.com>
List-Owner: <mailto:owner-lghtml@sprocket.lockergnome.com>
X-URL: <http://www.lockergnome.com/>
X-List-Host: Lockergnome <http://www.lockergnome.com/>
Reply-To: leave-lghtml-2534368N@sprocket.lockergnome.com
Sender: bounce-lghtml-2534368@sprocket.lockergnome.com
Message-Id: <LISTMANAGERSQL-2534368-1682723-2002.07.18-09.57.34--qqqqqqqqqq-lg#spamassassin.taint.org@sprocket.lockergnome.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
...
```

There aren't any rules or standards to the actual content in the files (I already had a difficult time decoding them).

Is there a way in python to parse this into something akin to a dictionary? I'm not super picky, although a dictionary would be lovely. Really, I just don't want to write a mammoth of a custom parser. I've tried a couple of standards (e.g. json.loads), but I haven't found anything that works universally.

Comment: I think RFC 4155 and RFC 2822 would be the place to start.